# Binding lost on @Html.EditorFor when I apply formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When using the following I lose the binding on the field

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quote.DiscountRate,  new { @class = "form-control pull-left " })
```

And the model field looks like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
public double? DiscountRate { get; set; }
```

if I remove the DisplayFormat the binding still works.
I also tried the following with the same result:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Entity.DiscountRate, "{0:P2}", new { @class = "form-control pull-left"  })
```

In both cases if I remove the formatting I get my binding back

Comment: How the view loses model binding? Please inspect HTML element generated on browser and paste the generated code as edit (or even including your view & controller code to help reproduce your issue). For MVC 5.1 and above, you may use `EditorFor` with `htmlAttributes`: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quote.DiscountRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control pull-left" }})`.

Comment: I think I have figured it out, but I'm surprised by the result. Per your suggestion, I looked at the generated code. In the case where I use formatting the value="15.00 %". In the case where I do not use formatting, the value ="0.150000000". Because the field is decimal, the formatted value is invalid so it doesn't bind. To me this seems a bit odd because I think most people would want to format the value so you would think that razor would support this. I guess I need to figure out a work around.

Answer (score 0):

What I have discovered is that when you apply a DisplayFormat, it is as the name suggests, for display. If you want to display a decimal value with formatting and make it available for editing, you have to handle the conversion from text back to decimal at post time -- or whenever you need the actual value.